# How to add my right-click context menu entry to the modern context menu in Windows 11?

Tags: powershell, shell, registry, contextmenu, windows-11

I've written this PowerShell script to automatically block executables inside a folder in Windows Firewall

```
$currentdir = get-Location
cd $currentdir



function FirewallBlock { 
    param ($exes)
    
    
           $exes | ForEach-Object { New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "$_.name inbound" -Direction Inbound -Action Block -Profile Any -Program $_.DirectoryName }
           $exes | ForEach-Object { New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "$_.name outbound" -Direction Outbound -Action Block -Profile Any -Program $_.DirectoryName }
                 
}


$programs = dir -Recurse *.exe
FirewallBlock ($programs)
```

Added it to the old style context menu by creating 2 registry keys here:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Firewall
```

and here

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Firewall\command
```

Firewall key has the default name and value of "Firewall Block Programs"

command key has the default name and string value of

```
powershell -command "Start-Process pwsh.exe -ArgumentList '-file C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Firewall.ps1' -Verb runAs"
```

How can I add this context menu option to the new modern context menu style in Windows 11?

so far I found this but couldn't figure out if I really have to create a program out of this simple PowerShell script in order to add it there or not.

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/

Comment: You need to implement `IExplorerCommand` in a DLL. From a quick search I found [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/AppModelSamples/blob/master/Samples/SparsePackages/PhotoStoreContextMenu/dllmain.cpp) in C++.

Comment: @zett42 Thank you, I'm not familiar with C++, could you explain more and possibly post a complete answer? it will help a lot of people since it's a new topic :)

Comment: I would have to research this on my own first, which I'm currently not interested in. Maybe there is a free tool to add custom entries to the new context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing for quite a while, and finally found the best way to do it!

You can actually do this without making an entire application for it. You can use the [Custom Context Menu](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/custom-context-menu/9PC7BZZ28G0X) app from Microsoft Store, it lets you add anything you want to the *new* Windows 11 context menu.

I've been looking for this every so often for like half a year, feels good now that I've found a working solution.